# Removing nested array with empty strings with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of arrays. Some of the arrays contain only a single empty string. I'd like to remove all of those from the parent array.

Before

```
[[ '*Order Number','*Line Number','*Item Number'],
[ '' ],
[ '018622','2','had-99']]
```

After

```
[[ '*Order Number','*Line Number','*Item Number'],
[ '018622','2','had-99']]
```

Comment: What if the array: `["abcd", "", "ijkl"]`? Should it be removed?

Comment: No, just the example above. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use built in [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for it.

```js
var array = [[ '*Order Number','*Line Number','*Item Number'], [''], [ '018622','2','had-99']];

console.log(array.filter(function (a) { return a.toString(); }));
```

Version which mutates the original array.

```js
var array = [[ '*Order Number','*Line Number','*Item Number'], [''], [ '018622','2','had-99']],
    i = array.length;

while (i--) {
    array[i].toString() || array.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: This works! It's ok that it returns a new array, a simple `var order_array = array.filter(function (a) { return a.toString(); });` assigns it to what I need.

Comment: With arrow functions is just pure awesomeness `array.filter(a => a + '');`. +1!

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably check both that the array only has length 1 and that the item is an empty string

```
var list = [[ '*Order Number','*Line Number','*Item Number'], [''], [ '018622','2','had-99']];

list.filter(function(arr){
  if(arr.length === 1 && arr[0] === '') {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better approach would be using `Array#splice`, which deletes specified elements from the parent array.

```js
var arr = [[ '*Order Number','*Line Number','*Item Number'], [''], [ '018622','2','had-99']];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i][0] == '' && arr[i].length == 1) {
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    --i;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```